# Python: Something went wrong somewhere in the list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, primes

```
>>> [l for l in range(2,100) if litheor(l)!=l in sieve(100)]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
>>> 2 in sieve(100)
True
>>> litheor(2)
True
```

So `litheor(2)` is `True` and `2 in sieve(100)` is `True`, so the `if` clause in the list comprehension is `False`. But why is `2` still in the output of the list comprehension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, at first it sounds crazy, but:

```
>>> True != 2 in [2,3,5]
True
>>> (True != 2) in [2,3,5]
False
>>> True != (2 in [2,3,5])
False
```

When you realise that this is not a simple precedence issue, looking at the AST is the only remaining option:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("True != 2 in [2,3,5]"))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=
Compare(left=Name(id='True', ctx=Load()), ops=[NotEq(), In()], comparators=[Num(n=2), List(elts=[Num(n=2), Num(n=3), Num(n=5)], ctx=Load())])
)])"
```

And here is a little hint:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("1 < 2 <= 3"))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=
Compare(left=Num(n=1), ops=[Lt(), LtE()], comparators=[Num(n=2), Num(n=3)])
)])'
```

So, it turns out, `True != 2 in [2,3,5]` is interpreted similar to `1 < 2 <= 3`. And your expression

```
litheor(l) != l in sieve(100)
```

means

```
litheor(l) != l and l in sieve(100)
```

which is `True`.

Comment: Thanks. 1, however, is not in sieve(100). Is there anything else that may have gone wrong?

Comment: @SylvesterVLowell Well, might be one of the following: 1) `sieve(100)` containing not only integers but also boolean `True`; 2) `litheor(2)` returning `2` instead of boolean and `sieve(100)` containing `0`. I can't see any other options. Could you show us your definitions of `sieve` and `litheor`, please?

Comment: @SylvesterVLowell Oh wait… You are right… That's totally crazy…